# Django Templates: Use different css for pages

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, django-views

New to Django, I want to use different css files for different pages - i.e. page1.css for page1.html, page2.css for page2.html. Is there a way to do this while still extending base.html?

In base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- css -->
  if page1.html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/page1.css" %}">

  if page2.html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/page2.css" %}">

  if page3.html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/page3.css" %}">

</head>
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
{% block content %}{% endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

In page1.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load staticfiles %}

    {% block body_class %}page1{% endblock %}
    {% block title %}Page1{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    Page 1
    {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**You can use the same concept that applies to `{% block content %}` in that you can fill it in or extend it on a page by page basis.**

Hence, in `base.html`, create a block called `styles` in the `head` section (or anywhere you want to load your CSS):

```
{% block styles %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now, you can extend this block on a per page basis in any of your templates that use `base.html`:

Example: `page1/template-view.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/page1.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```