# DJango 1.8 use completely different CSS on child template

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I want to do something in DJango templates. I am using Materialize CSS framework for a side bar which has a menu on it, it only has links to some views showing django forms, and that menu is my "base.html", so, it is a parent template. But i have a problem, i don't want to use Materialize CSS forms classes on my child templates, i want to use something completely different, because for my application materialize seems to be confusing for users.

I have tried this:
[Django Templates: Use different css for pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386868/django-templates-use-different-css-for-pages)

And it let me do some changes to CSS, but i want to absolutely remove parent template CSS and use only a particular CSS in my child templates (forms). Or use a CSS that only affects the parent template, not affecting child templates.

EDIT:
Read the comments for the solution. That answered exactly what i wrote at the beginning, but i think my question wasn't complete. I was looking for a solution similar to ASP.NET master pages, were a master page has its own CSS and this is not affected by WebForm CSS (child template), they are independent. In DJango if you override parent template CSS on a child template, parent will be affected. Now my menu looks nasty haha. But now i have a hint to only override the css classes that i need.

Comment: You can enclose your `css` link in your base.html within a `{% block %}`, and just override where you don't want it (otherwise the parent's css will be used as a fallback).

Comment: To  _completely remove parent template CSS_ - add all the css inside this `{% block css  %}<link_to_all_css>{% endblock %}` and override it in the child template with your desired css for that template. [otherwise the parent's css will be used as a fallback to other childs that don't override it].

Comment: @KapilSachdev What you told me was completely useful, thank you

Comment: Welcome. My answer was based on the fact that the base.html doesn't only have CSS to be extended but much more things than that. That's what template inheritance is for - to make stuff reusable and override those that should be changed.

Comment: @KapilSachdev I found what css rules i needed to override, and used !important just to make sure, and now everything is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Dont extend your child template with the parent base template. 
Which is dont include this statement in your child templates:

```
{% extends "<base-file-name>.html" %}
```